# Repeated measures assistance needed

Tags: repeated-measures, data-transformation, small-sample, split-plot

Disclaimer - I am not particularly adept at stats and have a relatively complicated design. I apologize in advance for my ignorance. Looking forward to any help I can get! Here goes...

I have 2 between-groups factors: A and B; A has 2 levels, B has 4 levels. I also have one repeated within-subjects factor: C (3 levels/time points).

My group sizes are small (*n* < 5) and uneven (*n* = 3 and *n* = 5, depending on group) [*N* = 36].

I am using SPSS to conduct a repeated measures assessment (split-plot rma, *I think)*. Despite that Box's Test of Equal Covariance is significant; a significant Multivariate effect is detected for C (*p* = 0 for all 4 corrections). No significant differences were detected for A x C, B x C, or A x B x C.

Mauchley's Test of Sphericity is non-significant and a significant difference in C was reported (*p* = .000) on both the within-subjects effects table and the within-subjects contrasts table.

Levene's Test of Equality of Error Variances reports significant differences for the first 2 of the 3 levels of C.

On the between-subjects test, only the intercept (?) was significantly different (*p* = .000) using transformed data (SPSS automatically transformed the data due to Levene's test results?), although B was close (*p* = .07).

So here are some of my questions...

What corrections/transformations might I do as a result the significant Box Test and significant Levene's Test? [Note that some of my data have a value of 0.00]. What is the intercept? Would a different analysis be more appropriate?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance!

Comment: Update...I tested the skew and kurtosis of my data and found a significant positive skew in all 3 levels of my dv (C). Thus, I conducted a log10 + 1 transform of my data and re-did my analysis, however Box's and Levene's tests are both still significant. I will try conducting a more powerful transformation (e.g., inverse transformation). I am not sure how to anchor my new distribution to 1 given the constant I added to deal with 0 values, nor am I sure if the new distribution must be properly anchored at 1 for the repeated measures test results to be accurate. Looking forward to your comments!

Comment: Another update...I conducted an inverse transform (1/(x+1)) of the raw data and re-ran the RMA. Box's test no longer yields significant results, yet the first level of C is still significant according to Levene's test. I am still not sure how to anchor the distribution appropriately. I am reading about how to run a Box-Cox transform instead of the inverse transform, but I think it may be more appropriate to run different, non-parametric between-groups tests instead. I also am not sure how to get SPSS to let me check the boxes for equal variance not assumed for my post-hoc tests. Please help!